# Mutating object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> Helpful note: Consider reading the **'What's the purpose'** part at the bottom, as I may not even have the best approach here, to begin with. Thanks.

Hey! So I've got this:

```
parent: {
    child1: {
        prop: 'hi there'
    },
    child2: {
        prop: 'hey there'
    }
}
```

I want to run some value-mapping magic to get it to be like this:

```
newObj: {
    child1: 'hi there',
    child2: 'hey there'
}
```

I want the mapping-function (or the correct name for this process) to essentially take the `prop` value of each child in `parent`, and set that value to the `value` part of a `key` that carries over the same name as on `parent`, if that makes sense.

**Is the property on each child object always named `prop`?**

Yes.

**Why not define it that way from the start?**

Because I've got other properties aside from `prop` that I need to use.

**What's the purpose?**
I'm using laravel. When I send this to the server for validation, I have to validate `child1.prop` rather than `child1`, which means the error messages send back as:

> child1.prop : "Something is invalid"

... and I want it to be

> child1:"Something is invalid"'

If there's a better way, please do suggest.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/odyahtjx/

Comment: @ChrisG why not an answer? it's perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the answer from @Chris G, so other users can find it easily:

```js
const parent = {
  child1: {
    prop: 'hi there'
  },
  child2: {
    prop: 'hey there'
  }
};

const newObj = Object.entries(parent).reduce((a, [key, { prop }]) => ({ ...a, [key]: prop }), {});

out.textContent = JSON.stringify(newObj);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I purposefully *didn't* post an answer. For one, the question requires heavy editing. It is about mutating an object and has zero to do with laravel or validation. Secondly, it is unlikely anybody else will benefit in any way from this question, assuming they will find it in the first place. SO isn't a "help me solve my problem" website; its purpose is to essentially build an exhaustive FAQ. This question/answer contributes nothing to that imo.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. I proposed an edit to this question but is not approved yet.